# Serve the new version of my website to my IP address via httpd.conf or .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a full update for my wp-based website (full rewrite from scratch).

I wonder if it's possible to serve the old website, but serve the new one for my IP address.

Is there a way to achieve this via httpd.conf or .htaccess?

```
If (IP_Address = 123.456.789) then
    # Serve content from /home/website.com/public_html/
else
    # Serve content from /home/new-website.com/public_html/
end if
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite you can use the `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` variable to detect what the remote ip is, and change your content root based on that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^127.0.0.1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsite/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /newsite/index.php

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php
```